# Issue with exiting out of pynput listener threads

Tags: python, multithreading, pynput

I'm having some issues with exiting out of the keyboard and mouse listening threads when they are opened together. My apologies in advance if any of the following is incorrect, I'm not entirely experienced with threading.

This post is tagged with multithreading. I'm unsure if this belongs to that category. Please let me know if it should be dropped.

For example, I have the following code in a class:

```
 def detection_start(self):
        with mouse_listener(on_move=self.on_move_mouse, on_click=self.on_click_mouse, on_scroll=self.on_scroll_mouse) as mouse_monitor:
            with key_listener(on_press=self.on_click_key, on_release=self.on_release_key) as key_monitor:
  
                key_monitor.join()
                mouse_monitor.join()
```

How do I terminate both `key_monitor` and `mouse_monitor` and exit out of the program? I've tried the following function and it doesn't seem to work.

```
   def terminate_program(self):
        key_listener.stop
        mouse_listener.stop
        sys.exit(0)
```

I'd appreciate any insights.

Comment: Are you calling `terminate_program` from the main thread, or are you calling it from one of the event handlers?